# passing parameters in python function

Tags: python

I have written one method in python as follows :

```
 def report(self,year,month):
    print year,month
    emptylist=[]
```

parameter month is optional. Sometimes it's NOT passed from the caller function but sometimes it is passed.How is this different from the following code ?
`def func(self,*args,**kwargs):print args,kwargs` I know this has simple answer but I'm new to python and programming stuff. Please help me out.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Comment: Thanks. It was so simple.

Comment: Okay! I have one last question here. If my rep becomes 0 will my account get deactivated ?

Comment: Rep cannot fall below 1, but your account may be banned for new questions if you post too many closed/downvoted questions. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation and http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Thank god! At least I can comment here :) I ask stupid questions I know but I'm still beginner here.

Comment: Why not ask better questions? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `month` has a default value, you can try

```
 def report(self, year, month='default_value'):
    print year, month
    emptylist = []
```

The value of `month` gets overwritten if passed

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ashoka's answer, it's normally a good idea to use `None` as the default value in the method's signature and assign the true default value with in function body. This makes it easier to wrap the function, pass arguments, and it also avoids problems with mutable default values.

```
def func(kwarg=None):
    if kwarg is None:
        kwarg = 'default'
    print(kwarg)

func()
func(kwarg='Hello')
```